# year() function in SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, semantic-web

I want to make a query in SPARQL that returns items of the year 2007.
I tried this :

```java
    String requete7String = 
            "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> "
          + "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> "
          + "PREFIX rss: <http://purl.org/rss/1.0/> "
          + "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "
          + "SELECT ?item "
          + "FROM <http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/SW-FAQ-feed.rdf> "
          + "WHERE { "
          + "  ?item rdf:type rss:item . "
          + "  ?item dc:date ?dateString ."
          + "  bind(strdt(?dateString, xsd:dateTime) as ?date) "
          + "  FILTER (year(?date) = 2007) "
          + "}";
```

But it returns nothing. The line `FILTER (year(?date) = 2007)` doesn't work.  However, I saw in SPARQL documentaiton that the function [year()](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-year) takes a dateTime and returns a integer, so can you tell me why it might not work?

Comment: Without seeing the data, none of us can say for sure.  My initial guess would be that the ?dateString isn't a legal lexical form for an xsd:dateTime, so the function given an error. If you remove the filter and just look at the values of ?dateString, what do you get?

Comment: If i remove the "filter line", and display ?date and ?dateString: it returns: http://pastebin.com/z8FEW2KJ

Comment: And if I add "bind(year(?date) as ?year)": http://pastebin.com/mx7SfiP1. The function year() returns nothing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2007-04-12T00:00+00:00"^^xsd:dateTime isn't a legal xsd:dateTime (the time part should be 00:00:00, not 00:00.  Therefore it is not a legal value and year(illegal) is error, and the filter is false.